# Print a div in landscape and a div in portrait on a same print

Tags: css

I would like to know if it's possible to print some part of a web page in landscape and other part in portrait.If yes, how?

More details:
I'm currently doing  a web page where we can found an image (in a div) and a table(in an another div).
The image is on a page and the table on an other page.
Sometimes my image need to be printed in landscape. The table is always in portrait.
So what I did for the moment is:
    `
                         $distanceY) {
                            ?>

```
                        <div  id="plancompletpaysage" class="impression-paysage">
                            <?php
                            echo '<img src="plan.php?restaurant=' . $_POST['restaurant'] . '&seance=' . $_POST['seance'] . '&date=' . $_POST['date'] . '&heure=' . $_POST['heure'] . '"  usemap="places" />';
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    if ($distanceX < $distanceY) {
                        ?>                   
                        <div  id="plancompletportrait" class="impression-portrait">
                            <?php
                            echo '<img src="plan.php?restaurant=' . $_POST['restaurant'] . '&seance=' . $_POST['seance'] . '&date=' . $_POST['date'] . '&heure=' . $_POST['heure'] . '"  usemap="places" />';
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>`
```

I try that:

```
<style>
 @media print{
            @page paysage{
                size: landscape;
            }

            .impression-paysage{
                page: paysage;
            }

        }  
</style>
```

Using that change nothing. Everything stay in portrait.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
This is the solution I find with the help @Mordecai :

```
                .impression-paysage{

                display: block;
                margin-top:120px;

                margin-left:-100px;
                text-align:center;
                width:140%;
                height:160%;
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
                zoom: 150% ;

            }
```

So 1st step: resize the div. The 2nd step: rotation of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page printing layout is portrait by default.

To print div *`.impression-paysage`* in landscape orientation, you can use `transform:rotate(90deg)` or `transform:rotate(-90deg)`.

```
@media print {
  .impression-paysage {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After that, I need to center my image because with the rotation I lost a part of it. So I added a margin-top.

Comment: but long text in a landscape element is lost. The end of the text will not move to the next page